# DB2 IF condition in trigger

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I have something like this in my trigger

`IF(VAR_ENABLED AND ((SELECT 1 FROM .... OR SELECT 1 FROM ...))` 
I noticed that the second condition is executed anyway when `VAR_ENABLED` is set to FALSE

Comment: You may want to have a look at WHEN part of a trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Search conditions](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=predicates-search-conditions)

> Search conditions within parentheses are evaluated first. If the order
> of evaluation is not specified by parentheses, NOT is applied before
> AND, and AND is applied before OR. **The order in which operators at the
> same precedence level are evaluated is undefined to allow for
> optimization of search conditions**.

Comment: But how I have to rewrite this condition above to make it works as expected, means when `VAR_ENABLED` is FALSE, then ignore other conditions, my approach will be `IF(VAR_ENABLED) THEN IF (other conditions)`

Comment: Yes, it's the only reliable method.